# Get HSB values from RGB color in NetLogo

Tags: colors, netlogo

NetLogo provides an [`extract-hsb`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#extract-hsb) that gets the hsb values for a NetLogo color. However, it doesn't appear to work on colors specified with an rgb list, even though rgb lists are legitimate colors in NetLogo. So my question is, how might one go about doing this manually?

BTW, I've added a feature request to NetLogo to extend `extract-hsb` appropriately: https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/643

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a generalization of `extract-hsb` based on [wikipedia's definition of HSB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Hue_and_chroma) (note that V and B are the same thing)

```
to-report to-hsb [ rgb-color ]
  if is-number? rgb-color [ set rgb-color extract-rgb rgb-color ]
  let r item 0 rgb-color / 255
  let g item 1 rgb-color / 255
  let b item 2 rgb-color / 255
  let v max (list r g b)
  let chroma v - (min (list r g b))
  let h 0
  let s ifelse-value (v = 0) [ 0 ] [ chroma / v ]

  if chroma > 0 [
    if v = r [
      set h ((g - b) / chroma) mod 6
    ]
    if v = g [
      set h (b - r) / chroma + 2
    ]
    if v = b [
      set h (r - g) / chroma + 4
    ]
    set h h / 6
  ]
  report map [ precision (? * 255) 3 ] (list h s v)
end
```

It matches `extract-hsb` perfectly on all color numbers except 44 for some reason...

```
observer> show filter [ (extract-hsb ?) != (to-hsb extract-rgb ?) ] (n-values 140 [ ? ])
observer: [44]
```

Unfortunately, it looks like NetLogo rounds RGB values when converting from HSB (well, this actually makes sense). This means that you can't do a perfect HSB->RGB->HSB conversion. For example, using the function above:

```
observer> show to-hsb hsb 30 64 128
observer: [30.547 63.75 128]
```

Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed on the issue. In the meanwhile, you can pass the list through [`approximate-rgb`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#approximate-rgb) to get a color that [`extract-hsb`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#extract-hsb) will handle:

```
to-report extract-hsb-from [ c ]
  report ifelse-value (is-list? c)
    [ extract-hsb approximate-rgb (item 0 c) (item 1 c) (item 2 c) ]
    [ extract-hsb c ]
end
```

(**Edit**: see Seth's comment below for big caveat, however.)

Comment: This will sometimes give good results, and sometimes quite bad, depending on whether there is something close to the input color in NetLogo's native color space.